# Can we choose a network adapter when sending data

Tags: linux, sockets, routes

When programming in linux sockets, we are invoking the standard libraries socket(), connect(), send() and so on, but if we have two network adapters connected to the same LAN, can we choose one manually or it depends on the route table configured by the administrator that we can't change or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can specify interface with [bind()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#bind), since every interface has its unique IP address.

Comment: but the parameter passed to bind() is the remote socket

Comment: @jason.foo: No, the parameter passed to `bind()` is a local address, to which you would like the socket to be bound.

Comment: @Hasturkun: yes, I made a mistake, I thought bind() functions is only for servers to restrict receiving incoming packets